# python compare 2 columns and write a 4th column with values from 1st column if column 3 matches column 2

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have 3 columns in an excel file. I would like to compare values in col 3 with values in col2. If the value exist in col2, write the value of col1 to col4. if the value is not in col2, write NA in col 4. col3 may sometimes be empty value in which case nothing to compare.

Example:
Excel file

```
col1    col2    col3
a2      2        4
1d      3        2
cc      5        3
12      4        1
```

Expected result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a2      2        4       12
1d      3        2       a2
cc      5        3       1d
12      4        1       NA
```

Still a work in progress. A pointer will be very helpful please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by another `Series` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), if not match `NaN` is by default:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)

df['col4'] = df['col3'].map(df.set_index('col2')['col1'])
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3 col4
0   a2     2     4   12
1   1d     3     2   a2
2   cc     5     3   1d
3   12     4     1  NaN
```

If possible duplicates in `col2`, error is raised:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Solution is add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
0   a2     2     4
1   1d     2     2
2   cc     5     3
3   12     4     1

df['col4'] = df['col3'].map(df.drop_duplicates('col2').set_index('col2')['col1'])
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3 col4
0   a2     2     4   12
1   1d     2     2   a2
2   cc     5     3  NaN
3   12     4     1  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrel. one more thing I found is that .0 is added at the end. i.e int in some initial columns becomes float. Do you know why?

Comment: @Starter - I guess there are added only integers, but if at least one NaN it convert values to floats, it is by design. But in last version of pandas is solution for integers with NaNs working together, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: @Starter - If add strings values, then no converting to floats, like in my answer. It is only `integer`s problem.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you much